# ¿Como redirigir hacia la dirección request.pat_info en un middleware django?

Tags: python, django

Buenas queridos amigos de stackoverflow, tengo mi siguiente duda en mi programa estoy creando una n cantidad de variables dentro de una lista de los **settings.py** con la finalidad de que al momento de tipiarlos a la url no tome en cuenta si el usuario este autenticado o no, por favor ayudenme con mi codigo aquí les dejo el middleware y el settings.

settings.py

```
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
    'accounts/login',
    'accounts/logout',
    'accounts/signup',
    )

PUBLIC_URLS = (
    '$',
    'admin/'
    )
```

middleware.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import logout
import re
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse

EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]


class middleware_login_required:

def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response

def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    assert hasattr(request, 'user')
    path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

    url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS)
    public_url = [re.compile(x) for x in settings.PUBLIC_URLS]
    redirect_public = any(y.match(path) for y in public_url)
    if redirect_public:
    #Aqui va el problema de redireccionamiento
        return render(request.path_info)
    if path == 'accounts/logout/':
        logout(request)
    if request.user.is_authenticated and url_is_exempt:
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    if request.user.is_authenticated or url_is_exempt:
        return None
    else:
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu problema. Pero es fácil darse cuenta que si lo que quieres es redirigir, no deberías usar la función `render` si no hacer como haces en otras partes de tu código, quedando así: `return redirect(request.path_info)`

Comment: @GermanAlzate Hola german, ya probe usando return redirect(request.path_info) y me da un error de redireccionamiento por esa razon hago mi pregunta de buscar una alternativa para esa linea de codigo que me ofreces. Gracias.

Comment: Qué error te sale? Sería bueno que indicaras qué has intentado, y qué resultados has obtenido, hasta los errores

Comment: @GermanAlzate German, el error que me sale, es que me llama varias veces al mismo return redirect(request.path_info) por el cual me sale el error en el navegador que el direccionamiento esta repetido varias veces, Me hace un llamado desde consola alrededor de 10 veces hasta 20. Por esa razón use el render. Si gustas te invito a intentarlo.